# Spydr install and open - Mac

Tags: python, spyder

I ran this code in Mac OS High Sierra terminal

```
pip install -U spyder
```

How do I open spyder as an interface? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to open Terminal.app then run there `spyder` or `spyder3` depending if you installed Spyder for Python 2 or 3, respectively.

Please notice that `pyqt5` (the graphical library used by Spyder) is only available through `pip` for Python 3, so if you're using Python 2, you'll have to find an alternative method to install it.

Comment: Any chance btw you know how I find out the location of my Anaconda python interpreter. By default Spyder has selected a different interpreter. If i run "python" from the terminal I will open my anaconda intepreter byt if I run "python3" from the terminal I will run the other one. I don't know how to find the location of my "python" intepreter thanks